# Support Library 27.1.0 onLoaderFinished returns a closed cursor when starting a Fragment

Tags: android, android-support-library, loader

After updating to Support Library 27.1.0, my application crashes and it appears to be caused by a CursorLoader returning a closed cursor in onLoaderFinished().

I'm using the Loader inside a Fragment and I'm not manually closing the cursor. If I rollback to Support Library 27.0.2, everything works. Here is the stack trace:

```
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: ...
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:151)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:123)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:237)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:259)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToFirst(CursorWrapper.java:71)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.test.onLoadFinished(LeaderBoardFragment.java:104)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.test.onLoadFinished(LeaderBoardFragment.java:41)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderObserver.onChanged(LoaderManagerImpl.java:221)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:109)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:121)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData.access$400(LiveData.java:59)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:416)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:368)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:292)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:332)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:137)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:123)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2377)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2595)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2382)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2337)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2244)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:702)
03-27 16:27:58.653 18706 18706 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
```

My code in onLoaderFinished() is the following:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    super.onLoadFinished(loader, cursor);
    int score;
    if (loader.getId() == MY_LOADER_ID && cursor != null
            && getAbstractAdapter() != null) {
        getAbstractAdapter().swapCursor(cursor);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            score = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(0));
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes when calling `cursor.moveToFirst()`

Code from `onLoaderReset()`

```
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you're using the Cursor? Sounds like you're using `changeCursor`, not `swapCursor`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for taking a look. Please see the edited question which includes code for the cursor usage.

Comment: @ianhanniballake After doing more digging in the codebase, I see that Loaders are only getting started using `restartLoader()` instead of first calling `initLoader()`. Digging into the SupportLibrary code, it looks like calling `restartLoader` will close the cursor in 'CursorLoader#onReset'. What's strange is that it looks like the LiveData is holding onto the previously delivered Cursor (which is now closed) and returns it to `onLoaderFinished` before delivering a new one.

Comment: That sounds like [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74135998), to be fixed in 27.1.1, coming out soon.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for the info. I'll wait for that release to see if it solves my issues. I really appreciate you helping out the community.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in support library 28.0.  Although I closed cursor in fragments onStop() on next appearance of fragment I got closed cursor - this helped me

```
override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>, cursor: Cursor?) {
        if (loader.id == LOADER_ID ) {
            if (cursor?.isClosed == true)
                loaderManager.restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this)
            else
                adapter.swapCursor(cursor)
        }
    }
```

although it looks like workaround - I thought that loader is somehow responsible for managing lifetime of cursor and assure new one when old id closed.